# Is there a way to use Qt's unit testing modules as part of a Code::Blocks project with the QtWorkbench plugin?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt, codeblocks

We're developing a Qt project using the Code::Blocks IDE with the QtWorkbench plugin. We'd like to take advantage of Qt's unit testing modules to test our code, but from [what I've read online](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/qtestlib-tutorial1.html), the only way to do so is to use `qmake` to manually create a new "project" and makefile for each unit test and then to build and execute that project.

Does anyone know of a way to integrate tests with our overall project to have them built and run automatically when the project is built, specifically within the context of Code::Blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.archivum.info/qt-interest@trolltech.com/2008-09/00297/Re:-Usage-of-QTestLib.html

http://qtcreator.blogspot.com/2009/10/automatically-running-unit-tests.html